JWT with Jupyterhub 4.x?
Does anyone have experience implementing JWT in Jupyterhub 4.x? I am attempting to use https://github.com/mogthesprog/jwtauthenticator but am running into 401s regardless of what I submit. My config in jupyterhub_config.py looks like this:
# JWT Config
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'jwtauthenticator.jwtauthenticator.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator'
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.secret = '<redacted>'             # The secrect key used to generate the given token
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.username_claim_field = 'username'
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.expected_audience = ''
c.JSONWebLocalTokenAuthenticator.create_system_users = False
#c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.header_name = 'Authorization'                         # default value

The service starts without issue. I am trying to generate a sample payload to feed into a browser bar to test logins, which I generate with the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                               
import jwt                                                                                                                                                                                     
import time                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
jup_payload = {                                                                                                                                                                                
            "iat": int(time.time()),                                                                                                                                                           
            "username": "testuser",                                                                                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                               
jup_jwt_token = '<redacted>'                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
jwt_string = jwt.encode(jup_payload, jup_jwt_token, "HS256")                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                               
print(jwt_string) 

I know from looking at the jwtauthenticator code that I need an Authorization header with bearer (yes, lowercase), but I'm unsure what to include there. Do I need a token associated with a defined role and service in the Jupyterhub config? When I attempt to define those and include the header in my generated token, I still get a 401.
Finally, what is the URL I should be testing against? I am using https://<hostname>:8443/hub/login?<token_generated_above> and also https://<hostname>:8443/hub/login?token=<token_generated_above>. Again, these result in 401 responses.
Some facts:

Jupyterhub runs fine with PAM authentication on the port defined above.
We are an LDAP shop. There are no local users in this deployment.
We are working on Jupyterhub v4.0.2.

Many thanks for any ideas or experience you can share.
Defined configs as instructed in JWT project README. Generated a JWT and attempted to feed it to the application in a browser.
